# Need to consume from Kakfa topic and provide cron expression dynamically (received from kafka topic) to quartz2

Tags: dynamic, apache-kafka, cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

Problem statement - I need to consume from a kafka topic, where i am getting cron expression as header and need to trigger the QUARTZ and need to provide the cron expression dynamically.

***Here is my code snippet -***

```java
from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}......")
    .routeId(routeId)
    //accessing all the header value and then forming a valid cron expression
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override 
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            String sec=exchange.getIn().getHeader("second",String.class);
            String min=exchange.getIn().getHeader("minute",String.class);
            String hours=exchange.getIn().getHeader("hours",String.class);       
            body=exchange.getIn().getBody();
            log.info("The original Body : {}",body);
            // Method call to prepare the cron expression based on the headers value
            cronExp=cb.getCronExperssion(sec,min,hours,"?","*","*","*");
            //Setting up the final cron expression to the header    
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("timerObject", timerObj); 
            log.info("The timer object values are: {}", timerObj);
            log.info("The original scheduled time is : {}",startPolicy.getRouteStartTime());
        }
    })
    // because the quartz2 route can’t be at the to side, it should always be a from() that's why i am using the mock:result here, Any better way ???
    .to("mock:result");

// Here I need to give the cron expression which is being stored in the headers.
from("quartz2://group1/trigger1?cron=0/20+*+*+?+*+*+*&stateful=true")
    .routeId(“Scheduler Route”)
    .log(“Scheduler routed started …”)
    .to(“direct:httpRoute”);
```

I have tried multiple things like, enrich (), PollEnrich, But not able to apply the cron expression from headers value. Please help ....

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Where are you setting `cronExp` in the headers? `exchange.getIn().setHeader("cronExp", cronExp);`

Comment: Its inside the .process() method, here is the code  ... Since its in header, I can't access it while forming a from("quartz2://group1/trigger1?cron="+timerInfo+"&stateful=true") section as i need to give cronExpression there.

Comment: Here is the code where i am setting up the headers .....process(new Processor() {
                  @Override
                  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                   //Retrieving exchange headers
                   String sec=exchange.getIn().getHeader("second",String.class);
                            String min=exchange.getIn().getHeader("minute",String.class);
                            cronExp=cb.getCronExperssion(sec,min,hours,"?","*","*","*");

Comment: I guess the problem here is updating the dynamic cron value in an outer class variable that too from anonymous inner class i.e. .process(new processor() { ......